# Notify after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2013

Hope this is an nice easy one
I want to show a notify when an ajax function completes. My ajax is fine I just can't seem to get the notify to work. I have jquery and everything installed and I also have notify.js from http://notifyjs.com/.

Using the google developer tools I just get the error below all the time.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.notify is not a function
```

Here is my ajax function. This works just fine exactly as I need just no notify is displayed :(

```
function MyAjaxFunction()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("mainpagemenu_myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            $.notify("Hello World"); // <- **** this is the thing I want to do
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/myaspfile.aspx", true);

    xmlhttp.send();           
}
```

I have linked in my files

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="/bootstrap/js/notify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you added the reference to `$.notify`? as error clearly suggest otherwise

Comment: Check the path of `$.notify`

Comment: what do you mean ? what path ? thats my problem I dont know what to add :(

Comment: Try with `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.21.0/css/components/notify.min.css` and `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.21.0/js/components/notify.min.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to the following script

`<script src="http://notifyjs.com/dist/notify-combined.min.js"></script>`

at the top of the page (before using the Ajax function)

Comment: Sometimes the solution is under our nose :) Please mark the question as an answer if it solved the problem.